# Is convex , lower semicontinuous function with closed domain continuous relative to its domain?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, convex-analysis

> Let $f: \mathbb R^n \to [0 , +\infty] $ be a lower semicontinuous and convex function. Assume $\mbox{dom} f = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n  | f(x) < +\infty \}$ is a closed set.  Prove or disprove that for all $x_0 \in \mbox{dom} f$, the function $f$ is continuous on $x_0$ relative to its domain ,i.e,  for all sequences $x_n \to x_0$ with $f(x_n) < +\infty$ we have $f(x_n) \to f(x_0) $
>
> Note, if $x_0 \in  \mbox{relative int dom} f$ then we are done, because of convexity of $f$, thus we only need discus about case when  $x_0 \in  \mbox{dom}f \setminus \mbox{relative int dom} f.$

P.S This is a question motivated by the question [Continuity relative to the domain of a convex function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3151905/219176)  which didn't get much attention.

Any help would be greatly appreciated .